# Appium Inspector ImageView

Tags: android, user-interface, testing, automation, appium

I'm using with Appium driver for Android automation testing
By the appium inspector I can recognize view elements ( like TextView, WebView etc.) but unfortunatley it doesn't recognize ImageView elements.
Ideas?

Comment: What's you question? Are you asking why it doesn't work or simply looking for workarounds? if it's the latter then you'd need to explain the scenario in which you use it.

Comment: I'm asking why it doesn't work? I'm trying to find the element by appiumDriver.findElement When I try to inspect the elements in the page, The appium inspector doesn't recognize the ImageView elements. But the others it is.

Comment: The "appium inspector" is one way of finding the elements. If you happen to try using the ruby_console => https://github.com/appium/ruby_console it will give you a different view of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Though any amount of code from would be good.
Still I believe you must once check the attributes of the object you are trying to use in the application codebase.

Answer (score -1):

**It does - 100% Appium inspector recognize ImageView element**. I have used many times.
Suggestion: Please crosscheck once, with actual element you are working with.